# Variable available thoughout java program (singleton)

Tags: java

I need to set a boolean variable at runtime that can be accessed by any other class (without having to pass the variable around from class to class).  This variable will be a configuration setting, and will depend on some value set by the user at runtime.

I suspect a singleton is the way to go, but having spent the morning reading up on it, I seem to find a lot of examples (& arguments) on the best way to create them, without any mention of how to actually use them.

Is singleton the way to solve this?

If so, can anyone provide an example of a singleton, that can have a boolean value set, that can be accessed statically from any other class?

EDIT: I'm such an idiot (totally overcomplicating the problem, and missing the simplest solution).

`public static volatile boolean yourBoolean;` Looks like it'll work perfectly

Comment: Please just give it a try and post what you have. stackoverflow is not a code writting machine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you just need a boolean value, there is no need to use a singleton. Just declare a:

```
public static volatile boolean yourBoolean;
```

(with the volatile keyword to make sure that all changes made are visible across threads if you are in a multi-threaded environment).

Comment: So why not `AtomicBoolean`?  Actually, I'll ask a question instead. :)

Comment: @DavidGrant Yes that would work too - AtomicBoolean uses a volatile variable internally. The semantics would be the same.

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859008/what-is-the-difference-between-using-a-volatile-primitive-over-java-util-concurr

Answer (score 2):

If the variable will contain a configuration setting **that won't change** during runtime, I suggest you use a `final static` variable. See the example below:

```
public class Main {
    public final static String CONFIGURATION_SETTING = "some_setting";
}
```

You can access this constant by using the following reference:

```
Main.CONFIGURATION_SETTING
```

It will be available throughout your solution, as long as you import the Main class.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a singleton is necessarily what you need here - as your question itself states, all that you need is a variable that can be accessed by any other class.

Since you don't want to pass anything round, it must be `static` - and of course it will have to be `public` in order for other classes to see it.

So the simplest way to achieve this would be something like the following:

```
public class Config {
    public static boolean flag;
}
```

Any class can then read the value as `Config.flag`.

If you have multiple threads in your application, you'll need to think about thread-safety.  For simple, single boolean values you can just mark the field as `volatile`.  But if you're doing something a little more complex, or updating several values at once, you'll need to ensure that these updates are atomic and visible to other threads in an appropriate fashion.