# What is the difference between using a volatile primitive over atomic variables?

Tags: java, concurrency

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: volatile boolean vs AtomicBoolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786825/java-volatile-boolean-vs-atomicboolean)

When is it appropriate to use a `volatile` primitive (e.g. `boolean`, `integer` or `long`) instead of `AtomicBoolean`, `AtomicInteger` or `AtomicLong`, and vice-versa?

Comment: Since one has mentioned it (neither here nor on the duplicate): w/ Atomic classes you have a nifty method lazySet. On most architectures it outperforms basic volatile write (but it doesn't have the same semantics). Basically lazySet doesn't need to flush the CPU write buffers which is pretty good as they can be flushed while the CPU is stalled.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The visibility semantics are exactly the same, the situation where using the atomic primitives is useful is when you need to use their atomic methods.

For example:

```
if (volatileBoolean) {
    volatileBoolean = !volatileBoolean;
}
```

could create issues in a multi threaded environment as the variable could change between the two lines. If you need the test&assignment to be atomic, you can use:

```
atomicBoolean.compareAndSet(true, false);
```

Comment: `volatileBoolean = !volatileBoolean;` can have a threading issue just by itself.

Comment: Because negating the boolean is a two-step operation?

Comment: @DavidGrant More likely a 3-step operation actually: read value, negate, assign value.

Comment: There are three steps; 1) get the `volatileBoolean` 2) flip it 3) set the `volatileBoolean`.  Any number of threads can be between step 1 and 3

Answer (score 17):

Using a plain volatile is simpler and more efficient if all you want to do is set or get the value. (But not get&set the value)

If you want more operations like getAndIncrement or compareAndSwap you need to use the AtomicXxxx classes.

Comment: lazySet on atomic usually wins over volatile 'write' (esp on TSO architectures) but it has different semantics.

Comment: lazySet is faster as it doesn't stall the CPU pipeline.

Comment: that's what i am saying, I mean AtomicXXX can be "more efficient" even if you just want 'set', just to clear that bit.

Answer (score 10):

The `Atomic*` classes wrap a `volatile` primitive of the same type.  From the source:

```
public class AtomicLong extends Number implements java.io.Serializable {
   ...
   private volatile long value;
   ...
   public final long get() {
       return value;
   }
   ...
   public final void set(long newValue) {
       value = newValue;
   }
```

So.

> When is it appropriate to use a volatile primitive (e.g. boolean, integer or long) instead of AtomicBoolean, AtomicInteger or AtomicLong

If all you are doing is getting and setting a `Atomic*` then you might as well just have a `volatile` field instead.

> ... and vice-versa?

What the `Atomic*` classes give you however, are methods that provide more advanced functionality such as `incrementAndGet()`, `compareAndSet()`, and others that implement multiple operations (get/increment/set, test/set) *without* locking.  That's why the `Atomic*` classes are so powerful.

It's also important to note that wrapping your `volatile` field using `Atomic*` class is a good way to encapsulate the critical shared resource from an object standpoint.  This means that developers can't just deal with the field assuming it is not shared possibly injecting problems with a `field++;` or other code that introducing race conditions.

Comment: better explanation than the one marked "answer".

Answer (score 8):

We have started to ban the use of `volatile` in our sources because it's very easy to write code which doesn't always work as expected.

In my experience, people add volatile to share a value between threads. And then, someone else starts to modify the value. And most of the time, this works. But in production, you start to get odd errors which are really hard to track down. Counters are incremented 100'000 times (tests only increment them 10 times) but end up at 99'997. In Java 1.4, long values could get corrupted really, really rarely.

The `Atomic*` helper classes, on the other hand, impose only a small overhead and they always work as advertised.

So unless you have a very good reason(*) to use `volatile`, always prefer the `Atomic*` helper classes.

If you don't know exactly what each character in the `Atomic*` helper classes does, then you should really avoid `volatile`.

*: Premature optimization is never a good reason.

Comment: *"it's very easy to write code which doesn't always work as expected."* => Could you be more specific? Do you mean people assuming volatile gives atomicity guarantees for example?

Comment: @assylias: I added some examples to my answer.

Comment: if you have races w/ volatile you are going to have them w/ atomic classes just as much. now that standard argument: counters. Using atomic classes as counters is not scalable anyways. While the modification of the atomic are to be well 'atomic' the data races still remain.

Comment: @bestsss: If you know exactly how `volatile` works, you can use it. But I bet that most of the Java developers out there don't, so I don't encourage anyone to use it.