# Java 7: IF condition triggered when false

Tags: java, if-statement, java-7

I have this piece of code:

```
void timerCountDown(){
    while(RaftNode.getTimeoutVar()){
        long x = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(x >= RaftNode.limit){
            System.out.println(x);
            System.out.println(RaftNode.limit + " THIS SHOULD BE LESS THAN");
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " THIS");
            System.out.println("TIMED OUT");
            raft.RaftNode.setTimeoutVar(false);
            nextRandomTimeOut();
            raft.RaftNode.onTimeOut();
        }
    }
}
```

So basically, this is a time-out function and the time-out is refreshed by another condition. My issue is that the  x >= RaftNode.limit condition keeps triggering even though it is false (through the print statements).

My console outputs:

```
1431532870542
1431532872508 THIS SHOULD BE LESS THAN
1431532870542 THIS
```

So x is indeed the current time, but even though it is less than the limit, the condition is being triggered.

I have no idea why!

The limit var is

```
public static long limit;
```

so nothing fancy here

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger?

Comment: Something is probably changing the limit between the comparison and the print statement

Comment: @bluebrain he is printing both!

Comment: Is RaftNode.limit mutable?

Comment: One thing I would note is you're calling `System.currentTimeMillis()` a second time.  Get rid of your third print statement because it's confusing,  you should be printing x there.  Granted this code executes fast enough that `System.currentTimeMillis()` is the same as the value you stored in x, but that's not guaranteed

Comment: @Kon - The way it's written, the limit will only ever be increased, so I don't think that would make a difference

Comment: Is this being run in a multi-threaded environment?

Comment: Can we see the definition of RaftNode.limit?

Comment: @StormeHawke - originally there was no x, I was just calling System.currentTimeMillis() on its own. The x was just for debugging purposes

Comment: can you show RaftNode code also please?

Comment: Save RaftNode.limit to a temp variable before enter the condition and check if still prints a larger number for the temp

Comment: Are you using threads? The update of the values of a shared variable can be delayed. Make `limit` volatile or so.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Please update with a minimal example which reproduces the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: As @JoopEggen suggested, try changing `public static long limit;` to `public voliatile static long limit;`

Comment: Make the limit a `public static ` **final** `long limit;`. If the compiler then complains somewhere, this "somewhere" might lead you to the answer.

Comment: @Marco13 That's a veteran developer suggestion, I like it. Make the compiler do the work.

Comment: @user3601503, I see you fixed your issue but it would have been better for debuggin to print the values before and after the `if` condition. It would have shown to you that value is changing between the calls.

Comment: @akostadinov I actually originally tried this, but when I did the bug went away - I'm not too knowledgeable on why this happened, perhaps printing the value forced it to update?

Comment: @JoopEggen   Is this a threading issue or JVM optimizer issue? Maybe the the If-stmt  remembered a lower value, because JVM optimizer "inlined" it?

Comment: @user3601503  are you in multi threaded env? Would you have gotten the error in single threaded mode as well?

Comment: @Mecon I was in a multi threaded env, several threads were able to update the var at once. I wouldn't have been able to complete the task with a single threaded mode so I am not sure!

Comment: It is basically a threading issue, a search on java `volatile` will point further. Rather silly but threads can have stale values of some variable altered by another thread. With `volatile` the compiler ensures with extra code that threads get updated values. That variable values are copied into a thread might be considered an optimization issue. But then look at JIT too, LL2 cache and so on.

Comment: @user3601503 Since this is a multi threaded env, I would suggest using "AtomicLong" instead of " volatile long".

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859008/what-is-the-difference-between-using-a-volatile-primitive-over-atomic-variables

Comment: @Joop you should post that as an answer so the OP can mark it and this question can be considered "answered"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can only be a problem using threads. The update of the values of a shared variable can be delayed. Make limit volatile or so.

It is basically a threading issue, a search on java volatile will point further. Rather silly but threads can have stale values of some variable altered by another thread. With volatile the compiler ensures with extra code that threads get updated values. That variable values are copied into a thread might be considered an optimization issue. But then look at JIT too, LL2 cache and so on.

*(started as comments.)*

Answer (score 1):

Could you try something like the following?

```
void timerCountDown(){
    long limit = RaftNode.limit;
    long raft_time = RaftNode.getTimeoutVar();
    long x = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while(raft_time){
        x = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(x >= limit){
            System.out.println(x);
            System.out.println(limit + " THIS SHOULD BE LESS THAN");
            System.out.println(x + " THIS");
            System.out.println("TIMED OUT");
            raft.RaftNode.setTimeoutVar(false);
            nextRandomTimeOut();
            raft.RaftNode.onTimeOut();
        }
        raft_time=RaftNode.getTimeoutVar();
    }
}
```